# How to separately detect hand from body after skin detection?

Tags: python, opencv

I have used skin detection to detect skin color, but in the process other body parts also get detected. Is it possible to detect the hand alone or is there any any algorithm to distinguish between hand and body?

Here is the image:

[image]

My code is provided below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
   ret,frame=cap.read()

   HSV = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   l = np.array([0, 50, 80], dtype = "uint8")
   u = np.array([23, 255, 255], dtype = "uint8")
   skinDetect = cv2.inRange(HSV, l, u)
   cv2.imshow('Masked Image',skinDetect)
   _,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(skinDetect,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
      # discard areas that are too small
    if h<30 or w<30:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
   cv2.imshow('Rectangle',frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is your hand always bigger than your head in the images where you want to detect it ? Is it always roughly the same shape ?

Comment: ... https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: Still my favorite xkcd comic up to this day ;)